# How can I check if a specific word is present which is a database key on a dicord.py message?

Tags: python, database, discord, bots, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create a to some extent intelligent bot in discord which can store funny_words in a repl database and laugh if these words appear in the messages sent.

But I can't find a way to check if any word in the message corresponds to any key in the database.

This is the part of the code that causes me problems, in line 69, I tried to go through the database as if it was an array but it returns an error:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

while (db["id"] > i):
if (db[i]) in message.content:

these are the lines

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.